# The number of columns in the two selected tables or queries does not match

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

**Here is my SQL .**

SELECT
    [Ledger Entries JC].[Object Code],
    DLookUp("Description", "ACTVTY and CMDTY Descriptions", "L4='" & [Object Code] & "'") AS [Object Code Description],
    Left([Ledger Entries JC]![Subsidiary], 2) AS L4,
    DLookUp("Description", "ACTVTY and CMDTY Descriptions", "L4='" & [L4] & "'") AS [L4 Description],
    Left([Ledger Entries JC]![Subsidiary], 3) AS L5,
    DLookUp("Description", "ACTVTY and CMDTY Descriptions", "L4='" & [L5] & "'") AS [L5 Description],
    Left([Ledger Entries JC]![Subsidiary], 4) AS L6,
    DLookUp("Description", "ACTVTY and CMDTY Descriptions", "L4='" & [L6] & "'") AS [L6 Description],
    Right([Ledger Entries JC]![Subsidiary], 4) AS L7,
    DLookUp("Description", "ACTVTY and CMDTY Descriptions", "L4='" & [L7] & "'") AS [L7 Description],
    [Ledger Entries JC].Amount,
    DLookUp("Budget", "Budget By Activity By Commodity", "WBS='" & [WBS] & "'") AS Budget,
    [L6] & "." & [Object Code] & "." & [L7] AS WBS,
    [Ledger Entries JC].Date
FROM
    [Ledger Entries JC]
UNION
    Transform
    Sum([Budget By Activity By Commodity].Budget) As [Total Of Budget]
SELECT
    [Budget By Activity By Commodity].L4,
    [Budget By Activity By Commodity].[L4 Description],
    [Budget By Activity By Commodity].Budget AS [Total Budget],
    [Budget By Activity By Commodity].L5,
    [Budget By Activity By Commodity].[L5 Description],
    [Budget By Activity By Commodity].L6,
    [Budget By Activity By Commodity].[L6 Description],
    [Budget By Activity By Commodity].L7,
    [Budget By Activity By Commodity].WBS AS WBS,
    [Budget By Activity By Commodity].[WBS Description],
    [Ledger Entries JC Qry].WBS AS [WBS 2],
    Sum([Ledger Entries JC Qry].Amount) As Amount
FROM
    [Ledger Entries JC Qry]
        RIGHT JOIN [Budget By Activity By Commodity]
        ON [Ledger Entries JC Qry].WBS = [Budget By Activity By Commodity].WBS
Group BY
    [Budget By Activity By Commodity].L4,
    [Budget By Activity By Commodity].[L4 Description],
    [Budget By Activity By Commodity].Budget,
    [Budget By Activity By Commodity].L5,
    [Budget By Activity By Commodity].[L5 Description],
    [Budget By Activity By Commodity].L6,
    [Budget By Activity By Commodity].[L6 Description],
    [Budget By Activity By Commodity].L7,
    [Budget By Activity By Commodity].WBS,
    [Budget By Activity By Commodity].[WBS Description],
    [Ledger Entries JC Qry].WBS
PIVOT
    [Budget By Activity By Commodity].[Object Code] In(57523, 57531, 57532, 57533, 57535, 57537, 57540, 57590, 57626, 57627, 57628, 57629, 57630, 58230)

Comment: You need to format your code so it is easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have UNION query, all selects in such kind queries should have the same quantity of fields with the same data type. Here you have 14 fields in first query and 12 columns in second, this generates error. Also you'll need to check data type for each column, they should correspond in both queries. Here is your formatted query, please edit in question, I cannot.

```
SELECT
    [Ledger Entries JC].[Object Code],
    DLookUp("Description", "ACTVTY and CMDTY Descriptions", "L4='" & [Object Code] & "'") AS [Object Code Description],
    Left([Ledger Entries JC]![Subsidiary], 2) AS L4,
    DLookUp("Description", "ACTVTY and CMDTY Descriptions", "L4='" & [L4] & "'") AS [L4 Description],
    Left([Ledger Entries JC]![Subsidiary], 3) AS L5,
    DLookUp("Description", "ACTVTY and CMDTY Descriptions", "L4='" & [L5] & "'") AS [L5 Description],
    Left([Ledger Entries JC]![Subsidiary], 4) AS L6,
    DLookUp("Description", "ACTVTY and CMDTY Descriptions", "L4='" & [L6] & "'") AS [L6 Description],
    Right([Ledger Entries JC]![Subsidiary], 4) AS L7,
    DLookUp("Description", "ACTVTY and CMDTY Descriptions", "L4='" & [L7] & "'") AS [L7 Description],
    [Ledger Entries JC].Amount,
    DLookUp("Budget", "Budget By Activity By Commodity", "WBS='" & [WBS] & "'") AS Budget,
    [L6] & "." & [Object Code] & "." & [L7] AS WBS,
    [Ledger Entries JC].Date
FROM
    [Ledger Entries JC]
UNION
    Transform
    Sum([Budget By Activity By Commodity].Budget) As [Total Of Budget]
SELECT
    [Budget By Activity By Commodity].L4,
    [Budget By Activity By Commodity].[L4 Description],
    [Budget By Activity By Commodity].Budget AS [Total Budget],
    [Budget By Activity By Commodity].L5,
    [Budget By Activity By Commodity].[L5 Description],
    [Budget By Activity By Commodity].L6,
    [Budget By Activity By Commodity].[L6 Description],
    [Budget By Activity By Commodity].L7,
    [Budget By Activity By Commodity].WBS AS WBS,
    [Budget By Activity By Commodity].[WBS Description],
    [Ledger Entries JC Qry].WBS AS [WBS 2],
    Sum([Ledger Entries JC Qry].Amount) As Amount
FROM
    [Ledger Entries JC Qry]
        RIGHT JOIN [Budget By Activity By Commodity]
        ON [Ledger Entries JC Qry].WBS = [Budget By Activity By Commodity].WBS
Group BY
    [Budget By Activity By Commodity].L4,
    [Budget By Activity By Commodity].[L4 Description],
    [Budget By Activity By Commodity].Budget,
    [Budget By Activity By Commodity].L5,
    [Budget By Activity By Commodity].[L5 Description],
    [Budget By Activity By Commodity].L6,
    [Budget By Activity By Commodity].[L6 Description],
    [Budget By Activity By Commodity].L7,
    [Budget By Activity By Commodity].WBS,
    [Budget By Activity By Commodity].[WBS Description],
    [Ledger Entries JC Qry].WBS
PIVOT
    [Budget By Activity By Commodity].[Object Code] In(57523, 57531, 57532, 57533, 57535, 57537, 57540, 57590, 57626, 57627, 57628, 57629, 57630, 58230)
```

Comment: Sergey, Its not begging its just for someone assistance if someone want to. And thanks for arranging it but still the prolems exist.

Comment: I didn't change anything in the query. Try to add two empty columns to second query, something like `,null as empty1, null as empty2`, then you will have the same quantity of columns in both queries.